# SimpleDateFormat parse to Date

Tags: java, date

I have field in class Test:

```
private Date date;
```

Code in main:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date now = new Date();
Test test = new Test();
test.setDate(sdf.parse(now.toString()));
```

But I have error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 08 14:10:23 GMT 2013"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

How Can I parse today date to sava

Comment: why not `test.setDate(now);` ? Or overcomplicated `test.setDate(sdf.parse(sdf.format(now)));`

Comment: You're sending a date that's not in the expected format. You should change your format to `EEE MM dd hh:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy` or change the String to convert into a date to `08.01.2013`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`now.toString()` is not a good way to represent a date as a string, because it uses a 'default' format. To represent a date to a string, you can use the `format(Date date)` method of `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date now = new Date();

String dateAsString = sdf.format(date); //"08.01.2013"
Date dateFromString = sdf.parse(dateAsString);
```

Comment: I think `String dateAsString = sdf.format(now);` is what you mean. Also worth mentioning that this dataFromString is set to midnight in the local timezone. Depending in how this data is used the date may be adjusted.

Comment: It isn't good solution, because I have result: Tue Jan 08 15:08:42 GMT 2013

I want 08.01.2013

Comment: sdf.format(date); gives you "08.01.2013". Please specify what you are trying to accomplish with this 'test'...

Comment: His code sets the time of day midnight in the Date. This is because a java.util.Date represents an instant in time, and not just the Date format. There are 3rd party libraries, such as Joda Time that do allow you to do what you want. [link] http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/